# Can you tell me how to get to Sesame Street?

Tags: usa, tours, new-york-city

I have nothing but fond memories of the children show Sesame Street, and I know that it's filmed somewhere in New York. Is there a way to visit the actual set? As part of a guided tour would be ideal, but not necessary.

Comment: When I was about 7 years old (1987), I was delighted to visit Central Park, where part of the opening sequence of Sesame Street was filmed, in which Big Bird (and others?) were shown on roller skates. The opening sequence has since changed (likely countless times), so it probably wouldn't have the same effect on modern audiences. :)

Comment: I saw this in the related bar from another stack exchange site. I thought it was a joke - Apparently not!

Comment: I think Sesame Street differs a lot per country.

Comment: I don't think Big Bird lives here, but... https://goo.gl/maps/kxtppG9XLh6pHiEXA

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*Sesame Street* is currently filmed at the [Kaufman Astoria Studios](http://www.kaufmanastoria.com/) in Queens, which does not offer public tours (though the [Museum of the Moving Image](http://www.movingimage.us/) is open to the public and located on the campus). According to the [Sesame Workshop FAQ](http://www.sesameworkshop.org/faqs/),

> *Sesame Street* is not filmed in front of a live studio audience and the set is not able to accommodate guests.

There is a Sesame Street theme park called [Sesame Place](http://sesameplace.com/) in Langhorne, Pennsylvania, about midway between Philadelphia and New York (near Trenton, New Jersey), owned and operated by Sea World.

Now, that is only for the original American version of *Sesame Street*. There are many different versions internationally, and some of those filming locations may allow visitors.

Comment: Sesame Place is specifically a water park. Even for the most massive of nostalgia buffs, I suspect it has very little appeal unless you're accompanying small children.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Exactly. ;)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz - Plus it is unbelievably expensive without discount or coupons.

Comment: I have been to Sesame Place recently and it does not have much appeal for me as a nostalgic lover of Sesame Street.  My kid liked it though.

Answer (score 20):

Sesame Street is filmed at [Kaufman-Astoria Studios](http://www.kaufmanastoria.com/) in Queens. The studio isn't generally open to the public, so unless you know somebody or are involved in a production I wouldn't count on a tour.

However, I'd highly recommend a trip to the nearby [Museum of the Moving Image,](http://www.movingimage.us/) which houses a number of Sesame Street artifacts, regular Jim Henson/Muppet film screenings, and later this year, will be opening a new permanent gallery space devoted exclusively to the work of Jim Henson, The Muppets, and Sesame Street.